# SignalR not recognizing some transport disconnects

Tags: signalr

I have noticed that SignalR does not recognize disconnection events at the transport layer in some circumstances.  If the transport is disconnected gracefully, either through dropping my VPN connection to the server, or issuing an ipconfig /release the appropriate events are fired.  If I am connected to the VPN and I either unplug the network cable or turn my wireless off, SignalR does not recognize we are disconnected until the VPN connection times out.  That is mostly acceptable because it does eventually realize it.  However if I am not using a VPN and I simply unplug the network cable or turn off the wireless, SignalR never recognizes a disconnect has occurred.  This is using SignalR 2.0.1 over WebSockets in a non CORS environment.  If I enable logging in the hub I see no events logged in the console after waiting for over 5 minutes.  One thing that bothers me that I do see in the log during start up is:

```
SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 1600000 and a connection lost timeout of 2400000.
```

Is this my problem?  I have tried manually setting my GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout to 30 seconds but it does not change any behavior in this scenario, or alter that log statement.  What else might I be overlooking here?

Edit:  I noticed in fiddler that my negotiate response has a disconnect timeout of 3600 and a keepalive of 2400 and that trywebsockets is false.  This particular server is 2008 R2, which I do not believe supports Web Sockets.  Does that mean long polling would be used?  I don't see any long polling requests going out in fiddler or the console.

Comment: Windows Server 2008 does not support WebSockets. This doesn't mean that long polling is used since there are two more transports that it will try first: Server-Sent Events and forever frame (IE only). See http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/introduction-to-signalr for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout settings were my problem.  I'm not sure why I originally did not see a change in the logging output when I adjusted the setting, but I went back to a sample app and saw things change there and now things are behaving properly.

It should be noted that the default settings for SignalR produce the following statement in logging output and that this is measured in milliseconds.

```
SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332 and a connection lost timeout of 20000
```

This is obvious when you read the information under Transport Disconnect Scenarios on the following page which says:  [The default keepalive timeout warning period is 2/3 of the keepalive timeout. The keepalive timeout is 20 seconds, so the warning occurs at about 13 seconds.](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events)